# cancel button without any action method throws and exception

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-tags

I am having an issue with the Struts (1.x) code that I'm currently looking at (which is 12 years old) when a cancel button is clicked. Here's the java code with action methods:

```
public class CustomerApproveTypeAction extends AbstractCustomerApproveTypeAction {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomerApproveTypeAction.class);
 
    public ActionForward edit(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("entering 'edit' method - QS: " + request.getQueryString());
        }
 
            return mapping.findForward("edit");
        }
 
         
        return mapping.findForward("home");
    }
 
    /**
     * Save the info from the screen (being edited)
     * 
     * 
     */
    public ActionForward save(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("entering 'save' method...");
        }
 
         
        return new ActionForward("/report.html?meth=viewResult&bc=" + kc);
    }
 
    /**
     * Approve the info from the screen (being edited)
     * 
     * 
     */
    public ActionForward approve(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("entering 'approve' method...");
        }
 
         
        return new ActionForward("/report.html?meth=viewResult&kc=" + kc);
    }
     
     
    public ActionForward unspecified(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return mapping.findForward("home");
    }
 
}
```

And here's how all the methods are called from the JSP (customerApproveType.jsp) and they all work fine when the Approve and Save buttons are clicked.

```xhtml
<tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
<html:submit
                    styleClass="button" property="approve"
                    onclick="this.form.meth.value='approve'">Approve</html:submit>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
<html:submit
                    styleClass="button" property="save"
                    onclick="this.form.meth.value='save'">Save</html:submit> <html:cancel
                    styleClass="button">Cancel</html:cancel></td>
        </tr>
```

However, as soon as cancel button is clicked, I keep getting:

```
[INFO] SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Action[/customerApproveType] does not contain specified method (check logs)] with root cause
[INFO] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Action[/customerApproveType] does not contain specified method (check logs)
 
so on and so forth ....
 
[INFO] org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Here's my `AbstractCustomerApproveTypeAction` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomerApproveTypeAction extends DispatchAction {
 
    public ActionMessages validateForm(ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request) {
    }
 
    protected void mapFormToBean(UpdateCustomerForm updateCustomerForm, Order order) {
 
    }
 
    private void fillCustomer(CustomerHandler cph, Order order) {
 
    }
    protected CustomerHandler updateOrderUsingId(Order order, Integer userId) {
 
    }
    protected void updateCtrfile(Order order, Case cs) {
         
    }
    protected CustomerFile makeCustomerFile(Order order, Case cs, CustomerHandler cph, Manager mgr) {
         
        return customerFile;
    }
}
```

and `struts-config.xml` where the bean is defined for `CustomerApproveTypeAction`

```xml
<bean name="/customerApproveManual"
        class="com.abc.web.CustomerApproveTypeAction"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="orderManager">
            <ref bean="orderManager" />
        </property>
         
</bean>
```

Since there is no onclick event of the cancel button like it's there for other buttons like `onclick="this.form.meth.value='save'"` (for example). Please explain if my thinking is incorrect here. I guess I can define an action method for the cancel button and call it like `"onclick="this.form.meth.value='cancel'"` but I was hoping that `unspecified` method would take care of it.

**Edit:**

Tried the approach mentioned in the answer and it still doesn't work.

```
public ActionForward cancelled(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return mapping.findForward("home");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `unspecified` method?

Comment: It's the one which is listed here : https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.struts/struts-extras/1.3.10/index.html?org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html

`Method which is dispatched to when there is no value for specified request parameter included in the request. Subclasses of DispatchAction should override this method if they wish to provide default behavior different than throwing a ServletException. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`<html:cancel>`](https://people.apache.org/%7Egermuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/cancel.html) button there's already mapped a method named `cancelled`. All you need is just add this method to your action class.

> ## [`DispatchAction`:](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.struts/struts-extras/1.3.10/index.html?org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html)
>
> If the value of the request parameter is empty, a method named `unspecified` is called. The default action is to throw an exception. If the request was cancelled (a `<html:cancel>` button was pressed), the custom handler `cancelled` will be used instead. You can also override the `getMethodName` method to override the action's default handler selection.

Comment: Thanks. I remember trying this and tried it again after looking at your answer and it still complains the same. I've edited my post with what I tried. Is there anything I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if I also need `"onclick="this.form.meth.value='cancel'"` in order for the `cancelled` handler to work?

Comment: If you write `cancelled` then it might work.

Comment: Yeah, it worked after writing it as `cancelled`. However, the surprising thing is that there is same cancel button at many places I found and it doesn't throws any exception there. Although there is no exception thrown at other places, the page displayed is a blank page. I was also getting the blank page in my scenario so I had to return the following in my cancelled method `return mapping.findForward("cancelled");` and then in the struts config, I had to define `<forward name="cancelled" path="/pages/admin/mypage.jsp" /> `

Comment: But isn't the way I've done same like defining any method? I could have defined any xyz method and then called it in the onclick handler just like other methods are called

Comment: The `cuncelled` method is already defined, you can override it it you need a custom implementation. Mapping another method is possible but you should provide a parameter that holds a method name.

Comment: So ideally, should it have just worked after adding the `cancelled` method in my action class? Since I had to add `"onclick="this.form.meth.value='cancelled'"` in my `<html:cancel` in order for it to work, I am wondering if what I did is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Why not? `<html:cancel>` is the same like `<html:submit>` but it skips validations. The framework gets a parameter passed to the action and performed if `isCancelled()` returns `true`. You should have to provide a parameter to be recognized to proceed.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for explaining. On a separate note,  I'm curious about `unspecified` method as well. Does that also need a parameter for it to start functioning or is it handled differently? Initially I thought that since there is no parameter in cancel button, `unspecified` is the one which is going to get called but it didn't work like that I suppose and my understanding of unspecified method is not very clear I suppose.

Comment: The method `unspecified` is an API method. Of course you can override it and change its logic by default it throws an exception when a parameter has an *empty* value. The blank page may signal that a default method `unspecified` is called.